# Error: svn: Can't create directory .svn': Permission denied

Tags: permissions, svn

When I run:

```
svn co http:://mysvnserver.com/trunk --username myuser
```

I get error:

```
svn: Can't create directory .svn': Permission denied
```

(I set folder permission to 755 with : `chmod -R 755` + `umask 022`, but I get error above)

What should I do?

Comment: Please update your [original question](http://askubuntu.com/q/31107/6969), do not create a new one if the original question has no answers or comments yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your command creates a directory named "trunk" in your current directory. You should have write permissions to that folder.

If you want to put the checkout in a different directory, pass it to the command:

```
svn --username myuser co http://host/trunk targetdirectory
```

`trunk` will be located at `targetdirectory/trunk`.

Comment: what should I do for avoid creation of trunk directory?

Comment: which permission should I set to my folder?

Comment: what das `ls -la .` says? What does `mkdir targetdirectory` say? (both command in the shell in the containing directory)

Comment: Use the target directory `.` (current directory) to avoid creation of the directory `trunk`. If you checkout into your home folder, permissions are usually fine. Otherwise, you need to give yourself write permissions. Can you post the current directory and the output of `ls -dl .`?

Comment: Thanks but ,the error said about problem to create .svn folder and not trunk. no trunk folder created

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. In my case when I did `ls -la` on `/svnrepo` y figured out that all files and directories were owned by root:root

So I simply made:

```
sudo chown -R myuser:mygroup /svnrepo
```

and it did it for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

somebody else help me already, I just need to be the owner of folder instead root

```
chown -R youruser:youruser /path/to/svn/working/dir
```